# Accessing object from another method in visual studio 2015 form buttons

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, object, methods

I'm working on an interface for a user to enter a name, number, and initial balance to create an account. Then allowing the user to withdraw or deposit money through a class called Customer with Deposit and Withdrawal methods.

I've done the account creation part successfully. The problem is that I've created a new object called cust1 when the account successfully completes, but that object cannot be accessed when the user presses the button to apply the deposit or withdrawal.

[the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FigWl.png)

The full code as of right now: http://pastebin.com/6HHdMLV1

The object declaration is at the bottom of this code here, this is the method for when the user presses the account create button.

```
private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fullName = " ";
        int accountNumber = 0;
        double initialBalance = 0.00;
        Boolean validName = false;
        Boolean validAccount = false;
        Boolean validBalance = false;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AccountNameInput.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your full name.", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }
        else if(Regex.IsMatch(AccountNameInput.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z ]+$")) 
        {
            if(AccountNameInput.Text.Contains(" "))
            {
                fullName = AccountNameInput.Text;
                validName = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full name must contain a space.", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name must not contain numbers or special characters.", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AccountNumberInput.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your account number", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }
        else if(Regex.IsMatch(AccountNumberInput.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
        {
            accountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(AccountNumberInput.Text);
            validAccount = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must contain only numbers.", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InitialBalanceInput.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your initial balance", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(AccountNumberInput.Text, @"^[0-9.]+$"))
        {
            initialBalance = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(InitialBalanceInput.Text),2);
            validBalance = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Initial balance must contain only numbers and a decimal point.", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }

        if(validName == true && validAccount == true && validBalance == true)
        {
            AccountBalanceDisplay.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(initialBalance);
            Customer cust1 = new Customer(fullName, accountNumber, initialBalance);
        }
    }
```

And here is the method that isn't able to access the cust1 object.

```
private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double userInput = Convert.ToDouble(AmountInput.Text);

        if (DepositRButton.Checked)
        {
            cust1.Deposit(userInput);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add a reference to the object outside of the method that you create it in.

```
    private cust1;

    private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your code
    }
```

And now you can just replace

```
Customer cust1 = new Customer(fullName, accountNumber, initialBalance);
```

with

```
cust1 = new Customer(fullName, accountNumber, initialBalance);
```

Assuming that you need more than one customer you might want to use a list. This way you can just create the object like you did and add it to that list.

```
List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();

    private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Rest of your code
        if(validName == true && validAccount == true && validBalance == true)
        {
            AccountBalanceDisplay.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(initialBalance);
            Customer cust1 = new Customer(fullName, accountNumber, initialBalance);
            CustomerList.Add(cust1)
    }
```

And you can access the customer by it's position on the list:

```
private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double userInput = Convert.ToDouble(AmountInput.Text);

    if (DepositRButton.Checked)
    {
        CustomerList[0].Deposit(userInput);
    }
}
```